# Spring Boot controller unit test is not working with security. When POST, returning 404 not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have configured Spring Security, and when I try to test the controller, it doesn't work because, for example, when testing the POST method, it returns a 404 error code (not even 403 or 401).

SecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JpaUserDetailsService jpaUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/offers/**", "/companies/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .userDetailsService(jpaUserDetailsService)
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

JpaUserDetailsService.class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JpaUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .map(SecurityAppUser::new)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + username));
    }
}
```

JobOfferController.class

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JobOfferController {

    public static final String OFFER_PATH = "/offers";
    public static final String OFFER_PATH_ID = OFFER_PATH + "/{offerId}";

    private final JobOfferService jobOfferService;

    @PostMapping(OFFER_PATH)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createOffer(@RequestBody JobOfferDto offerDto) {

        JobOfferDto savedOffer = jobOfferService.saveNewOffer(offerDto);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Location", OFFER_PATH + "/" + savedOffer.getId().toString());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

JobOfferControllerTest

```
@WebMvcTest(JobOfferController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class)
class JobOfferControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private JobOfferService jobOfferService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    private JpaUserDetailsService jpaUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldCreateOffer() throws Exception {
        JobOfferDto offerDto = createTestOffer(null, "test", "test", "test", "test");
        JobOfferDto savedDto = offerDto;
        savedDto.setId(1L);

        given(jobOfferService.saveNewOffer(any(JobOfferDto.class))).willReturn(savedDto);

        mockMvc.perform(post(JobOfferController.OFFER_PATH)
                        .with(user("user").password("password"))
                        .with(csrf())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(offerDto)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().exists("Location"));
    }
```

I tried to exclude security from this test, but I want to have it. This test method returns 404 not found and I have no idea why.

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<404>
Expected :201
Actual   :404

Comment: "I changed @WebMvcTest(JobOfferController.class) to
@WebMvcTest @Import(JobOfferController.class)
and it works. Could someone explain why this is the case?"